# Ensure consistent ObjectMapper behaviour on GET/POST requests

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have a method similar to the following that already exists and works fine:

```java
@PostMapping(
      value = "/store",
      consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> postConversionEvent(@RequestBody Event event) {
  ...
}
```

It's now also become necessary for information to be posted via a GET method, as follows:

```java
@GetMapping("/store")
public ResponseEntity<String> postConversionEventAsGet(Event event) {
  ...
}
```

For all intents and purposes, we can assume that the `Event` class looks contains a single `org.joda.time.DateTime` field. To support this, I have a custom `ObjectMapper` that supports the parsing of `DateTime`s from string timestamps. e.g. the following request would work fine:

Body of a POST to `/store`:

```
{
  "date": "238572349834"
}
```

However, when I send this as a GET, e.g.:

```
https://someUrl.com/store?date=238572349834
```

I receive the following error:

```
Field error in object 'event' on field 'date': rejected value [238572349834]; codes [typeMismatch.Event.date,typeMismatch.date,typeMismatch.org.joda.time.DateTime,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [Event.date,date]; arguments []; default message [date]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.joda.time.DateTime' for property 'date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.joda.time.DateTime] for value '238572349834'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "238572349834" is malformed at "8572349834"]
```

It looks as though this parsing is not using the same `ObjectMapper` as the POST method. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: What does a successfull post request look like?

Comment: {
  "date": "238572349834"
}
This is parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like GET requests aren't serialised using an `ObjectMapper`, but are instead mapped using a `WebDataBinder`.

This class was created:

```java
public class DateTimeFromTimestampEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

  @Override
  public String getAsText() {
    return Long.toString(((DateTime) getValue()).getMillis());
  }

  @Override
  public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    setValue(new DateTime(Long.parseLong(text), DateTimeZone.UTC));
  }

}
```

I then added this method to the controller:

```java
@InitBinder
public void dataBinding(WebDataBinder binder) {
  binder.registerCustomEditor(DateTime.class, new DateTimeFromTimestampEditor());
}
```

The previously failed GET request (`https://someUrl.com/store?date=238572349834`) can now be deserialized successfully.